# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() where is mistake?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, arguments, syntax-error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/content_view.php
>
> Line Number: 8

Model:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');
  class Mat_model extends CI_Model
  {
    public function get_mat()
    {
      $query = $this->db->get('materials');
      $query->result_array(); 
    }
  }
?>
```

View:

```
<div id="breadcrumb"><a href="">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="">Somewhere</a></div>
    <div id="right">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Set Amir</h1>
      <span class="postinfo"> Posted by <a href="">Dylan</a> on 07.09.06</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amir tolos and tacos for plenty to see. jack is the orange sub marine, by any means I found my plans. </p>
      <hr />
      <h1>
      <?php foreach ($news as $one):?>
      <?if(is_empty($one))?>
      <?=$one['author']?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </h1>
      <span class="postinfo"> Posted by <a href="">Dylan</a> on 07.09.06</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amir <a href="">tolos</a> and tacos for plenty to see. jack is the orange sub marine, by any means I found my plans. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('menu_view');
        $this->load->view('categories_view');
        $this->load->view('useful_sites_view');
        $this->load->model('mat_model');
        $data = array();
        $data['news'] = $this->mat_model->get_mat(); 
        $this->load->view('content_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
    }   
}
?>
```

So where is my mistake? I can't find it.

Comment: Don't use PHP short open tags - `<?`. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your function.

You probably want something like:

```
public function get_mat()
  {
    $query = $this->db->get('materials');
    return $query->result_array(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen- is right. In model not return any value so, actually error occurred like that. I give advise to you please check the data which is retrieve from data base like ..

```
      $this->load->view('useful_sites_view');
      $this->load->model('mat_model');
      $data = array();
      $data['news'] = $this->mat_model->get_mat(); 
      echo "<pre>";print_r($data);exit;
```

so, there is no chances of such errors.